# EF Eager fetching derived class

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I´m using EF6 and trying to eager fetch the whole structure of an object. The problem is that i´m using inheritance.

Let´s say that i have this classes.

**DbContext**

```
DbSet<A> A { get; set; }
```

**Example classes**

```
public class A
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public IList<Base> Bases { get; set; }
}

public abstract class Base
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public abstract class Base1 : Base
{
    public SomeClass SomeClass { get; set; }
}

public class Base2 : Base1
{

}

public class Base3 : Base1
{
    public SomeOtherClass SomeOtherClass { get; set; }
}
```

The error i get is:

```
The Include path expression must refer to a navigation property defined on the type. 
Use dotted paths for reference navigation properties and the Select operator for collection navigation properties.
```

Why doesn´t it work with the following ?

```
    public IEnumerable<A> GetAll(string id)
    {

        return _ctx.A
               .Include(x => x.Bases.OfType<Base1>().Select(y=>y.SomeClass))
               .Where(x => x.Id.Equals(id)).ToList();
    }
```

**New example**

```
public IEnumerable<A> GetAll(string id)
{

   var lists = _dbContext.A.Where(x => x.Id == id);
   lists.SelectMany(a => a.Bases).OfType<Base1>().Include(e=>e.SomeClass).Load();
   lists.SelectMany(b => b.Bases).OfType<Base3>().Include(e => e.SomeOtherClass).Load();

   return lists;
}
```

EDIT: Added a new example that seems to work.

Comment: have you tried using `Include("SomeOtherClass")`?

Comment: Someclass is another Entity. I havent tried SomeOtherClass since SomeClass doesnt work yet

Comment: this means that you have tried `Include("SomeClass")` and it does not work?

Comment: yes, I get the error i wrote in the post :(

Comment: I think you are hitting one of the limitations of the TPH (and EF inheritance in general).

Comment: @Henrik Do you have an inverse navigation property in `Base` like `public A A { get; set; }`?

Comment: @IvanStoev No, i´ve only got a reference to Bases from A class.

Comment: Then at least I guess you have PK in `Base` like `Id` or something?

Comment: The real ids i need to compare with is in A in this case. But yes Base has an Id but i cant compare with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shortly, it's not possible out of the box.

The only workaround I can suggest is to materialize the master query result, then execute several `OfType` queries with the necessary `Includes` using the same filter as the master query, and rely on EF navigation property fixup.

It requires an inverse navigation property in the `Base` class:

```
public abstract class Base
{
   // ...
   public A A { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can use something like this:

```
public IEnumerable<A> GetAll(string id)
{
    var a = _ctx.A.Where(x => x.Id == id).ToList();
    _ctx.Base.OfType<Base1>().Include(e => e.SomeClass).Where(e => e.A.Id == id).Load();
    _ctx.Base.OfType<Base3>().Include(e => e.SomeOtherClass).Where(e => e.A.Id == id).Load();
    return a;
}
```

The same idea can be used w/o inverse navigation property but with using the returned base Ids as filter:

```
public IEnumerable<A> GetAll(string id)
{
    var a = _ctx.A.Include(e => e.Bases)
        .Where(x => x.Id == id).ToList();

    var baseIds = a.SelectMany(e => e.Bases.OfType<ModelA.Base1>().Select(b => b.Id));
    db.Base.OfType<Base1>().Include(e => e.SomeClass)
        .Where(e => baseIds.Contains(e.Id)).Load();

    baseIds = a.SelectMany(e => e.Bases.OfType<Base3>().Select(b => b.Id));
    db.Base.OfType<Base3>().Include(e => e.SomeOtherClass)
        .Where(e => baseIds.Contains(e.Id)).Load();

    return a;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. :) I've tried your first example, but without inverse navigation property (A ref in Base) and without having Where on both Base1 and Base3 ? I've updated my post. Will my example do exactly like yours or what is the difference ?

Comment: @Henrik Good catch! That's actually the third way using the same basic idea.  It's a variation of my first approach and although all the 3 approaches work, this seems to be the best for such scenario.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is not in the `Select(y=>y.SomeClass)` it self, if you try to remove it from your query and execute your query again, you will get same problem. You cannot query the inherited type as child and you expect from entity framework to take care for everything.

If you look to your database, the table `Base` has a reference to `A` which is relation 1-many from A to Base.

you can either get all the `Base` entities where `A.Id = something`, by adding a navigational property `A` in the class `Base`, and in your DbContext you add `DbSet<Base> Bases{get;set;}` then your query will look like this

```
var details = _ctx.Bases.OfType<Base1>()
                        .Include(t=>t.Box)
                        .Include(t=>t.SomeClass)
                        .Where(t=>t.Box.Id ==something);
```

Other option, to use a DTO, in the below sample I used `Anonymous` type, but you can create a strongly DTO typed to meet your requirements.

```
var details  = _ctx.A
                   .Where (t=>t.Id ==something)
                   .Select(a => new {
                        Id = a.Id,
                        // ... other A properites , 
                        Bases = _ctx.Bases.OfType<Base1>().Select(m=> new {
                            Id = m.Id,
                            Name = m.Name,
                            SomeClass = m.SomeClass
                        });
                   }
```

Hope this will help you