# EntityFramework Core: Eager loading navigation properties of derived types

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-sql, entity-framework-core

I'm using EntityFramework Core, and am trying to eager-load navigation properties that only exist on some derived type (all within a single query).
Probably best to demonstrate with a simple example.

Assume you have some data structure like

```
class Transaction
{
    public Product product { get; set; }
    public DateTime date { get; set; }
}

abstract class Product
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

class PhysicalProduct : Product
{
    public Photo photo { get; set; }
}

class Service : Product
{
    public Person provider { get; set; }
}
```

And some DbContext

```
class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Transaction> Transactions;
}
```

How can I query MyContext.Transactions to return all transactions, and include (eager load) Transaction.product.photo (in case product is PhysicalProduct), and Transaction.product.provider (in case product is Service) ?
As mentioned, trying to achieve this with only one query.

I've tried the following:

```
// This is conceptually what I want to achieve.
// Not very surprisingly, this will throw an InvalidCastException
Transactions
  .Include(x => ((PhysicalProduct)x.product).photo)
  .Include(x => ((Service)x.product).provider)
  .ToList();

// Based on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7635152/entity-framework-eager-loading-of-subclass-related-objects
// Projection into an anonymous type, then transform back.
// doesn't work though, throws an InvalidOperationException, e.g.
// The property "photo" on entity type "Product" could not be found. Ensure that the property exists and has been included in the model.
// i.e. even though I wrapped this in a condition (x.product is PhysicalProduct), seems like EntityFramework still tries to execute or parse the statement thereafter even if the condition is not true.
var query = Transactions.Select(x => new
{
  _transaction = x,
  _physicalProductPhoto = (x.product is PhysicalProduct) ? ((PhysicalProduct)x.product).photo : null;
  _serviceProvider = (x.product is Service) ? ((Service)x.product).provider : null;
})
.ToList()  // Execute query. Exception will be thrown at this step.
.Select(x =>
{
  var result = x._transaction;

  if (x.product is PhysicalProduct)
    ((PhysicalProduct)x.product).photo = x._physicalProductPhoto;
  else if(x.product is Service)
    ((Service)x.product).provider = x._serviceProvider;

  return result;
})
.ToList();
```

Can anyone think of a way to achieve this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yesterday I was fighting similar issue in EF6 - [EF Eager fetching derived class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39602011/ef-eager-fetching-derived-class/39603629#39603629). Currently EF Core is not better in that regard - in fact it's worse, because from the 3 EF6 workarounds only the #2 works here.

The workaround is:

It definitely can't be done with a single query. You need to execute the master query and materialize the result in memory. Then for each derived navigation type, collect the PKs and execute a query filtered by these keys. At the end, due to EF navigation property fixup you'll end up with all the navigation properties loaded.

```
var transactions = db.Transactions.Include(e => e.product).ToList();

var productIds = transactions.Where(e => e.product is PhysicalProduct)
    .Select(e => e.product.Id).Distinct();
db.BaseProducts.OfType<PhysicalProduct>().Include(e => e.photo)
    .Where(e => productIds.Contains(e.Id)).Load();

var serviceIds = transactions.Where(e => e.product is Service)
    .Select(e => e.product.Id).Distinct();
db.BaseProducts.OfType<Service>().Include(e => e.provider)
    .Where(e => serviceIds.Contains(e.Id)).Load();
```

Comment: Thanks Ivan! Unfortunately that is likely to void most of EF's IAsyncEnumerable benefits; plus its giving me bit of a headache as I can't execute and fetch the keys into memory, that seems to generate wrong SQL with EFCore and GUID-Keys, so need to keep ids as an IQueryable as you did in your example (productIds) - bit of a hinderance for a multi-level case though, e.g. including a reference of a derived type of a property which itself is on a derived type.
Anyway, hope I can figure that out; thanks for your input, that was very helpful!

Answer (score 3):

This isn't yet supported in EF Core. See https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/3910 for the issue tracking it.

I believe the only workaround is to execute multiple queries and let the EF context do the fixup for you.

Comment: Thanks Arthur. Bummer such a crucial feature isn't implement at all in EFCore. The workaround is causing some issues (described in reply to Ivan's post) unfortunately, but seems like this is the only way to go at the moment then

Answer (score -1):

I am to believe from the linked documentation that by using "ThenInclude". You are able to accomplish this. Sorry but I did not try it myself, so I can not verify that it works.

```
var blogs = context.Blogs
.Include(blog => blog.Posts)
    .ThenInclude(post => post.Author)
    .ThenInclude(author => author.Photo)
.Include(blog => blog.Owner)
    .ThenInclude(owner => owner.Photo)
.ToList();
```

https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/querying/related-data.html

Comment: Thanks. I believe .ThenInclude is intended for sub-references (as in your example), not for casting types though. I.e. if Blogs.Posts if of Type Post, and DerivedPost is derived of Post, it wouldn't allow you to include any property specific to DerivedPost either