# EntityFramework code-first inheritance with eager include relationship on derived class

Tags: c#, entity-framework, inheritance

I don't think using TPH or TPT inheritance method influence on this.

My goal is to have a single method that load everything from the database with mixed types of entities that may have separate relationship depending on the type.

Let's take this code-first model (simplistic mock-up to represent my problem):

```
public abstract class Entity
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public abstract class EntityWithInfo : Entity
{
    public AdditionalInformation Info { get; set; }
}

public class DerivedEntityWithInfo : EntityWithInfo
{
}

public class DerivedEntityWithInfo2 : EntityWithInfo
{
}

public class DerivedEntityWithoutInfo : Entity
{
}

public class AdditionalInformation
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int SomeProperty { get; set; }
}
```

And the Fluent API Configuration:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Entity>()
    .HasKey(e => e.ID)
    .Map<DerivedEntityWithInfo>(m => m.Requires("Type").HasValue(1)
    .Map<DerivedEntityWithInfo2>(m => m.Requires("Type").HasValue(2)
    .Map<DerivedEntityWithoutInfo>(m => m.Requires("Type").HasValue(3);

modelBuilder.Entity<EntityWithInfo>()
    .HasRequired(e => e.Info)
    .WithRequiredPrincipal()
    .Map(e => e.MapKey("Entity_FK"));

modelBuilder.Entity<AdditionalInformation>()
    .HasKey(e => e.ID);
```

Or visually:
[image: Visual]

With the SQL schema being simple:

```
Table Entity with: Id, Type, Name
Table AdditionalInformation with: Id, SomeProperty, Entity_FK
```

Now, I want to be able to do something like:

```
context.Entity.Where(t => t.ID = 304 || t.ID = 512).ToList();
```

This gives me correctly the list of all entities, and properly typed. But, of course the Info property is always null. Disabling LazyLoading and removing virtual don't force to load it either, as I understood I absolutely need to have a .Include(t => t.Info) line in there.

I know I can call

```
context.Entity.OfType<EntityWithInfo>().Include(t => t.Info).Where(t => t.ID = 304 || t.ID = 512).ToList();
```

But then I will only get entities derived of EntityWithInfo, and not the DerivedEntityWithoutInfo ones.

So let's try with an union:

```
context.Entity.OfType<EntityWithInfo>().Include(t => t.Info).Cast<Entity>()
    .Union(context.Entity.OfType<DerivedEntityWithoutInfo>().Cast<Entity>())
    .Where(t => t.ID == 719 || t.ID == 402);
```

This does not work, it tells me "Entity does not declare navigation property Info".

And also, I guess this would create one hell of a SQL query.

In fact, the very reason why I'm on this is because of a very old project that was using LINQ2SQL doing the equivalent with "LoadWith" options generating an abusive SQL query (duplicate the relationship table in a join for every inherited type). Loading a single entity take more times than loading the entire table of thousands of elements raw without hierarchy. So I was trying to see if porting to EntityFramework would generate a more optimal SQL query.

So, is there a way to do this or we are simply trying to do something the wrong way? This doesn't seems to be a very popular method to have both inheritance, relationship on derived classes, and eager loading because I find pretty much no resource on that online.

At this point, any suggestion on how to create this object model from this database model would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Eager loading of derived entity is not supported even by latest EF Core. See [Materializing an ICollection structure containing subclasses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45787939/materializing-an-icollection-structure-containing-subclasses/45795052#45795052), [EF Eager fetching derived class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39602011/ef-eager-fetching-derived-class/39603629#39603629) and similar for possible workarounds.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, and sorry for my late reply. The first link look like an interesting solution, I'll try with my complex model to see if it's viable or not. Otherwise I might just drop SQL altogether and switch to a key/value pair mutable json schema.

Comment: In any case, you can post this comment as a answer and I'll accept it since "It's not supported" is the real answer.

Comment: You are welcome, glad it helped :) However I've commented instead of answering because the question is duplicate (of some of the links or similar), so let it stay this way (appreciate the proposition though :) Feel free to can post self answer if you wish. Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is now supported in [EF Core 2.1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data#include-on-derived-types). Now to see if the resulting query is not too much performance-hungry.